# Get HTTP response body content from site for parsing with PHP

Tags: php, curl, url, screen-scraping

I know there are lots of articles on how to get response with Curl and then decode it but non of them worked. Sending request with CURL. Getting response. Dumping response content on the screen shows only "String(996)". I guess its compressed string. Tried to decompress it but didnt work.
Here is my case if someone can help me with that.
I tried this code with different url and it worked.

```
<?php
//set up variables
$url = 'https://en.bidfax.info';
$response = get_web_page($url);
var_dump ($response);

function get_web_page($url) {
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
  CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
  CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
  );

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  $content = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
  return $content;

}
```

Went through all posts about curl and gzdecode / encode.

Comment: That sounds about right. When you download it in a non-browser client, the site simply returns some JavaScript and nothing else (you can try it in something like PostMan). It's clearly designed either to a) generate all its content dynamically using JS with AJAX or websockets, perhaps, and/or b) prevent scrapers from accessing it by requiring a bit of JavaScript to load before it will allow you access to the content.

Comment: If you watch your Network tool while loading it in the browser for the first ever time, you'll see it loads the page with nothing much in it, then loads a JS file, and then it redirects you. So the JS is clearly redirecting you to the real content, and possibly adding a cookie (I didn't check but it would be common) so that next time it knows you're loading from a browser and not another tool. So basically, they don't want you to scrape their content and have taken active measures to prevent it.

Comment: you are absolutely right about JS and cookies. So I understand they dont want me to scrap their site and made some precautions for this but is it possible to do it?

Comment: function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("4ac24e1356c47ab69bdf290747c0f695"),b=toNumbers("1c066d8154d95da872a6dbb1a3da8"),c=toNumbers("7077e24a9a212be5f944eac28404047a");document.cookie="FORT="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="https://en.bidfax.info/?fortespro_42=1

Comment: this is response

Comment: @ADyson I disabled JavaSript on my Browser. I still got the site's content. So how is it a JS redirect? Most likely it is the cookie or ssl/tls issues.

Comment: @Misunderstood did you do that before you ever visited the site for the first time? Or on a later visit? If a later visit then perhaps you already have the cookie which lets the server provide you the content.

Comment: Basically this JS function shows which cookie it creates. I can open that cookie and see whats in it. How can I send it to server to respond with content of the page? Or is there a easier option for scrapping? What would be the option? How do I mark your response as good solution?